# Entity Framework code first migration throws exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an asp.net MVC application using entity framework code first in which I have 3 projects. One is a class library project in which I put my Domain objects and DataContext class.  In another project I put my admin MVC project,  and the third project is the front end MVC application.  I created a reference to my Domain project in my MVC application.

I enabled code first migration on my Domain object class library project and added first migrations initialCreate.  Then I executed Update-database command.  The database is created and my admin MVC application is able to access the data and  everything is good. But when I rebuild my Domain object class library project the MVC application throws an exception as follows:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The model backing the 'BookManyContext'
>   context has changed since the database was created. Consider using
>   Code First Migrations to update the database
>   (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

But actually I won't touch my domain object nor context class. Even my MVC application won't access the data, and throws the exception.

What's wrong with my approach?
Do I need to put my Context class in a separate project?

Comment: which version your EF?

Comment: @xudong125 Iam using EF 6.0.0